# Adding Navigation Bar on Tab-Bar Based App

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a tab-bar based app and I want to add Navigation Bar at the top of the app. Please note that I am using a library called [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) that creates 2 TableViews inside 1 parent ViewController.

What I tried was, adding a new ViewController and Editor->Embed in Navigation Bar. Place it before Tab Bar Controller, ctrl+drag to Tab Bar Controller to set the relationship of root view. Finally set Nav Bar Controller as initial view controller. But this fails like this:

[image]

(Top became pretty weird, blurry and the sub-header of PageMenu got disappeared. Maybe it's under that blurry thing because I can still swipe between 2 table views.

[image]

Secondly, I tried removing the Navigation Controller, and add Navigation Bar to the ViewControllers manually. This worked for table view and view controllers but not the PageMenu one. When I tried it on PageMenu Controller, it didn't show any navigation bar.

Please note that, in the Demo, they used Navigation Bar as Parent and sub-TableViews, and they achieved Navigation Bar with this as well as Storyboard > Navigation Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "HEADER"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  }
```

Lastly, I tried..

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let nav1 = UINavigationController()
    let first = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    nav1.viewControllers = [first]

    let second = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    let nav2 = UINavigationController()
    nav2.viewControllers = [second]

    let tabs = UITabBarController()
    tabs.viewControllers = [nav1, nav2]

    self.window!.rootViewController = tabs;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

    return true
}
```

But the result I get is:

[image]

What I want to achieve (but with TabBarController; NavBar just for header):

[image]

What I have now is this. I just want to add NavigationBar at the top of it like the above PageMenu example

[image]

---

**Update:**
Lasly, I also tried:
[image]

But same issue:
[image]

Comment: In short are you want `PageMenu` with `UITabBarController`?

Comment: I edited question. Please check below. What I want is like instagram. Both header, pagemenu & tabbar. My tabBar & PageMenu is working fine, I just couldn't add NavigationBar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also create like wise story board that helps to solve your problem.

[image]

Here I can created sample code what you want no single line code change but changes into storyboard only.

[Download source code from here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVigM97JuzCclYzakwxWDBYOWc)

Comment: I tried your solution. NavBar > TabBar > NavBars > Views. But I receive that blurry thing again. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sDZsP.png

Comment: @senty if you satisfy with my answer kindly accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Check this image]

Not add Editor->Embed in Navigation Bar before Tab Bar Controller
add Editor->Embed in Navigation Bar before  of View controller which you connect from  Tab Bar controller.

Because its work for particular Tab Vise so we have to add Editor->Embed in Navigation Bar before  of View controller

Comment: So I should have Tab Bar will extend to 4x NavController & each NavController to each View.? Like `TabBarController-> 1) NavBar -> View1 -> TableView1+2 , 2) NavBar -> View2 -> TableView3+4 , 3) NavBar -> View3 , 4) NavBar->View4` ?

Comment: I tried exactly that but same issue. I am adding it at the bottom of question

Comment: Ok check the View controller simulated matrics Topbar is  None? if None then select infrared

Comment: How can I check that? :s If I understood right, everything in all views are Inferred

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/SimulateBars.html check this link

Comment: Everything is selected inferred

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96965/discussion-between-rushang-prajapati-and-senty).