# NavigationBarButton Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is it common issue when connecting tabBarController using `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, the navigationBarButtons don't show ? And is there a proper way to fix this particular issue ? Because when I connect the views using segue, the buttons show just fine on navigationBar ..

Please help.

It's a big project, I couldn't take a picture of the whole project but this is a small part of it.

[image]

Comment: your tab bar should be the root view controller.

Comment: But I need the navigationController for the navigation bar, right? If I make the tab bar controller the root view of the table, the navigation bar would disappear ..

Comment: This will help you understand-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591350/how-to-add-navigation-interface-after-create-a-tab-bar-controller-programmatical

Comment: you can do this with storyboard as well.first embed tab bar with your view controller .After that embed navigation controller.

Comment: Would you please explain how to do it with storyboard? Thanks

Comment: Its explained here-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085415/adding-navigation-bar-on-tab-bar-based-app

Comment: I tried everything and yet navigationBarButtons and backButton aren't showing in the navigation bar ..